# iOS multipeer connectivity how to send data to specify device when connected to more than one device

Tags: ios, objective-c, multipeer-connectivity

now i face a problem on iOS multipeer connectivity send data. Can i send data to specify device only however 4 device connected together ? For example when device A send data to device B, device C and device D cannot receive. But now, when i send data through

```
sendData:dataToBeSent
toPeers:allPeers
withMode:MCSessionSendDataReliable
error:&error
```

device C and device D also receive the data. Please help

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [`sendData:toPeers:withMode:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCSessionClassRef/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MCSession/sendData:toPeers:withMode:error:)? Did you not see the parameters `toPeers:`? RTFM!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send the data using local URL or web URL to specific peer  then you can use the below method.

```
sendResourceAtURL:withName:toPeer:withCompletionHandler:
```

Otherwise you can pass the array with selected peerID to below method as argument for toPeers

```
sendData:toPeers:withMode:error:
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks your reply. But when i pass my peerid to it, system show warning below "Incompatible pointer types sending 'MCPeerID *' to parameter of type 'NSArray *'". This is the method i get peerID "MCPeerID *peerID = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"peerID"];"

Comment: U have to place the receiver peerID in array and give that array as input

Comment: Hi, i have try to put peerID in array like NSDictionary *dict2 = @{
                           @"peerID": peerID
                           };
    
    [_testArray addObject:dict2];     But when i send the testArray to "toPeers" error come out "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9feafd2540'
*** First throw call stack:". Can help ?

Comment: hi, thanks a lot. i have success place receiver peerID in array.

Answer (score 0):

You can send datas (for example a json file) to a peer by specifying the peer ID to whom you are connected by using the generated MCSession.

```
NSError *error;
    buddy.outputStream = [self.session startStreamWithName:@"myProfile"
                                                    toPeer:peerID
                                                     error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error while sending data: %@", [error description]);
        return;
    }
```

Where buddy is just a custom NSObject that realizes stream delegate's methods.